# Question regarding measurable random variable

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If $X_i, i=1,\dots, d$ are $F_T$-measurable random variables, is $\Pi_{i=1}^d X_i^k$ ($k$ is constant) also $F_T$-measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, since $f:(x_1,...,x_d)\mapsto\prod_{i=1}^dx^k_i$ is a continuous function (I assume your random variables have values in $\mathbb{R}$) and therefore measurable we have that $f(X_1,...,X_d)$ is a measurable random variable.

Comment: So if $\xi$ is a $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable and $f$ is a continuous function, then $f(\xi)$ is also $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable?

Comment: As long as you use the Borel-sigma-algebra, yes. (If you have random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ then it is standard to use the borel sigma-algebra)

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell the references for this?